# How to use preg_match to find html tags?

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I'm trying to make this code work by seeing if the returned data contains any html tags with php but it doesn't seem to work..

```
function returnRegflow() 
{
    $data = "<html><body>";
    return $data;


    if(preg_match('html', $data))
    {
        echo 'error';

    } else if(strpos($data, 'regflow') !== false){
        echo $data;
    }
}

echo returnRegflow();
```

Comment: `preg_match` expects a regulular expression. Have you tried with that? More importantly, most of your code does not run, because you exit your function before the `if`

Comment: I see, I'll try that then and instead of returning the data, I'll echo it. Edit: there's actually no need to echo the $data.

Comment: You need delimiters on the regex.

Answer (score -1):

Some issues:

- Your function is exiting too early by the `return` before the `if`, so it never got to checking for tags;
- `preg_match` expects the first argument to be regular expression, so it needs a delimiter at the start and the end (like `/`);
- A function that tests the variables it has set itself is a bit useless, you should pass it the string that should be tested: that way it can be used for different strings;
- using `echo` to output the result is not how functions work. Instead return the result, as a string or maybe as a boolean;

You seem to be looking for something like this:

```
function returnRegflow($data) {
    if (preg_match('/<\w/', $data)) {
        return 'contains tags';
    }
    if (strpos($data, 'regflow') !== false){
        return $data;
    }
    return 'does not contain "regflow"';
}

echo returnRegflow("<html><body>");
```

The check for tags is quite rudimentary: it checks whether the text contains anything that looks like `<a`, where `a` can be any letter.